# How to calculate the average after counting distinctly?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I would like to take the average after counting distinctly.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT product_id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT shop_id) AS shops,
         year,
         month,
         day
FROM X
GROUP BY  product_id, year, month, day
```

But now, I want to take the average of the shops. I've tried something like this, but I am getting this error: invalidrequestexception

```
SELECT product_id,
         AVG(COUNT(DISTINCT shop_id) AS shops) as avg_shops,
         year,
         month,
         day
FROM X
GROUP BY  product_id, year, month, day
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try like below

```
with cte as
(
SELECT product_id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT shop_id) AS shops,
         year,
         month,
         day
FROM X
GROUP BY  product_id, year, month, day
) select product_id,
         AVG(shops) AS  as avg_shops,
         year,
         month,
         day
FROM cte
GROUP BY  product_id, year, month, day
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the average, use a subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(shops)
FROM (SELECT product_id, COUNT(DISTINCT shop_id) AS shops
      FROM X
      GROUP BY product_id, year, month, day
     ) x
```

Comment: Should I remove X at the end of the query?

Comment: @zineda . . . It is a table alias.  There is no need to remove it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I think it's clearer if you put [`AS x`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8731a747fa4400c3b5cc2b87eb725dcc) (or `AS tab`) - although Oracle (for some reason which **completely** escapes me) [rejects](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=431ff54c01f08bffedcfa9d73da6e22c) this syntax!

Comment: @Verace . . . I never use `as` for table aliases, only for column aliases.

Comment: @zineda - the query won't work if you remove it. The first part of the query could also be written `SELECT AVG(x.shops) FROM (SELECT...` - see my fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8731a747fa4400c3b5cc2b87eb725dcc). Try removing it and see - SQL Server's error message isn't very informative, but PostgreSQL and MySQL for example, tell you that `ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias` - try it and see for yourself!